# Luigi - Executing 2 pipeline jobs, (Must be in SYNC, not paralell)

Tags: python-2.7, luigi

I am into Luigi framework development and I want to execute 2 jobs(Both are pipeline-jobs) in a single class, But in a way that Job2 must only run, when Job1 is executed completely.

```
class ExecuteTwoJobs(luigi.Task):
    def requires(self):
        reqs = []
        reqs.append(Job1(*args, **kwargs))
        reqs.append(Job2(*args, **kwargs))
        return reqs

    def output(self):
        //statements

    def run(self):
        //statements
```

Is there any way I can execute job1 and once it's completed, then go for execution of Job2.

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The way to do that is running Job2, being Job1 required by Job2.

```
class Job2(luigi.Task):

    def requires(self):
        yield Job1(*args, **kwargs))

    def output(self):
        //statements

    def run(self):
        //statements
```

Then you run Job2 this way:

```
luigi --module <your_module> Job2 <tasks params>
```

and luigi will first run Job1, and after it is complete, it'll run Job2.

Comment: Thanks for providing the solution, Yes We actually must do it in your way, But what I wanted is to execute them in a single class and Can't make Job1 required by Job2. 
Say Job3 requires both Job1 and Job2, So In this case Once Job3 is executed: Job1 and Job2 are pipelined, 

Is there any way: I can make Job1 to execute even before Job2 get started.
Thanks in advance

Comment: @TalatParwez I think you're not understanding how Luigi works o I'm not being able to understand you. The way to run the task I posted as solution is `luigi --module your_module Job2 <tasks params>`: that way Luigi will check if Job1 has alredy been run and if not, it will execute it. After Job1 is complete, it will run Job2. notice that you have never told Luigi to run Job1 (from command line), you just asked it to run Job2.

Answer (score 1):

In ordinary cases @matagus 's answer is recommended, but if you can't make `Job1` required by `Job2` for some peculiar reason, you can use [dynamic dependency](http://luigi.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tasks.html#dynamic-dependencies) as below.

```
class ExecuteTwoJobs(luigi.ExternalTask):

    def output(self):
        //statements

    def run(self):
        yield Job1(*args, **kwargs)
        yield Job2(*args, **kwargs)
```

When this task is executed, `Job1` is executed if not completed, and `Job2` is run after that. We can get less benefit of DAG workflow management, though.